# How to clear a form on uncheck with checkbox

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have added a checkbox to a PDF that copies duplicate address info with a checkbox on MouseUp:

```
getField("addr1").value = getField("addr2").valueAsString;
```

Now I want to reset the same field on uncheck. Would I use function:

clearForm(myFormElement.element.elements?
How would I insert that into the script I have?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (via google search), I was coding the wrong field. The above script I placed on the CheckBox not the text field. So it only imported text in and could not clear text on uncheck.

I should have Custom validated the field I want to import text into (addr2) with the script:

```
event.value = (getField("CheckBox").value=="Yes") ? getField("addr1").value : "";
```

credit to try67 https://acrobatusers.com/forum/forms-acrobat/populate-text-field-when-checkbox-checked/